# I've made changes to a storyboard after saving a snapshot, now my changes won't reflect when I compile my code. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, xcode, commit

I'm working with xcode 4.2 on a project. I enabled the local git repository on project creation, but hadn't been using snapshots. I decided to make a change that I wasn't sure I wanted to keep, so I stored a snapshot prior to making the code changes.

After making the changes, the running application seems unchanged in the simulator.  The storyboard has changed, replacing some components with others, and these changes aren't even reflected.

I've tried committing the project several times, and it seems to like to recommit my user prefs file each time, however I can't get it to commit the storyboard changes.

Has anyone encountered this? Am I missing something?

Comment: did you clean build, reset simulator?

Comment: lol. Thanks.. I missed the obvious one in not cleaning first!

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed a bug on XCode 4.5, when renaming the storyboard, it gets kind of frozen in time. Any changes after that wont reflect at runtime, not even doing a Clean Build or even removing the app from the simulator or device.

I renamed my storyboard to the old name (MainStoryBoard) and suddenly all my changes were reflected.

Answer (score 2):

Try this it worked for me.

- go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and delete your Application. { appname concatenated {some random number} }
- Reset your Simulator
- Clean your and rebuild it your App

Comment: Reset your stimulator?!?!

Comment: @herbrandson I mean remove the app from simulator. Reset to default state.

Comment: I think he means that you wrote "Stimulator" instead of "Simulator". But thanks for the answer, I'm having the same problem and I can't seem to figure it out so I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean out the build folder. Command-Option-Shift-K does it.