# Designing existing app with IB has no effect on device (iOS 7.1 / XCode 5.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I have encountered quite a strange bug a few days ago. It turns out that any changes in Interface Builder don't affect actual design anymore when the app is being tested on the device.

Practically it means, that you can go as far, as completely remove all view controllers in Storyboard, but with no effect on the device — the application will look the same. No changes at all.

At the same time, IB still works normally if you run the app in the simulator. New projects also work fine, as well as my other existing apps. So the problem seems specific for this particular project and not easily reproducible.

If anyone has faced with a similar bug or knows its probable reason, please let me know. Any advice will be of great help. Thank you!

p.s. I have installed XCode 5.1 and upgraded my device (iPad 2) to iOS 7.1 just a day or two days before the problem initially occurred. An upgrade might cause the bug, but I haven't seen similar complaints on the web yet.

p.p.s Unfortunately, I had no chance to test this bug on iOS 6.x or <7.1 devices, but I will do it as soon, as I'll get access to one of these devices.

Comment: clean project and erase from device. Delete the built package from xcode, does problem persist?

Comment: I've tried cleaning, reinstalling the app, removing `DerivedData` folder... nothing of help so far.

Comment: Have you removed/replaced a storyboard/xib? [connect storyboard to controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370208/how-to-connect-storyboard-to-viewcontroller)

Comment: Maybe you must manually remove some files, like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336942/ive-made-changes-to-a-storyboard-after-saving-a-snapshot-now-my-changes-wont)

Comment: Thank you very much, your comment led to the solution: I replaced my storyboard with its copy and now everything is fine! Still don't know what was the underlying problem though.

Comment: This is pretty strange, but renaming new storyboard copy from `MainStoryboard_iPhone2.storyboard` to original name caused same problem to reappear. So I have to keep new name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49874/discussion-between-mikejd-and-david-karlsson)

Comment: unfortunately not available for chat atm. but pls tag my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in  XCode.
Any changes that wont reflect at runtime, not even doing a Clean Build or even removing the app from the simulator or device.

Fix: rename storyboard to the old name (MainStoryBoard) and suddenly all changes were reflected.

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336942/ive-made-changes-to-a-storyboard-after-saving-a-snapshot-now-my-changes-wont)

Comment: This answer led me to solution. Though in my case I had to rename `MainStoryBoard_iPhone` (which is default name) to something different (e.x. `MainStoryBoard_iPhone2`). Anyway, thank you for help!